# Add layer to photo on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add a layer to a photo that will be upload by the user and let him download the new photo.
someone knows a plugin to Wordpress or a code template?

thanks ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress plug-in can be used:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-logo-uploader/

This is a plugin that makes it incredibly easy to upload your logo to any Genesis Child Theme. You basically use WordPress Customizer, upload your logo, and your done.

Comment: It is cost 59$ (the Genesis Framework) and i would like to see a website that is using this plugin before I pay, can you send me an example?